# Authentication and Authorization design for REST API

Tags: authentication, spring-security, oauth-2.0, authorization, openid-connect

I'm designing a system with REST API. REST API will be implemented using Spring Boot. The system should manage employee, product, orders information. It can be used as a standalone or as a part of some existing product ecosystem. I'm looking for some resource (book, blog, online course, etc.) to help me decide how to implement authentication and authorisation.

It's quite obvious how to do it if the system is used as a standalone product. User credentials/authorisation data can be stored in the same database next to product/employee and other data.

I'm not sure how to handle everything when the application is a part of some existing ecosystem. What if:

1. Someone wants to reuse existing User data store for authentication or third party service like Okta or Auth0.
2. Use existing data to build authorisation rules. For example authorise a person to modify product data if the person belongs to some User group.

I'm thinking about Oauth2+OIDC solution. For example Okta allows add a Claim based on Expression. User groups can be provided as Claims too. It seems Okta could be a source of both Authentication and Authorisation information. I'm not sure if it's a correct way to use Oauth2 and OIDC? What are potential pitfalls storing the authorisation data this way?
I've checked Keycloak and it seems authorisation data. can be stored there. So it's not an unusual practice to manage such a data in an authorisation server.
Maybe I should use Oauth2/OIDC for authentication only? Authorisation data (assigned roles, groups, etc.) can be stored in my application database. The application should provide means to manage the information.

I'd like to get some advice or source of information for this topic.
Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

I would aim to keep OAuth data fairly small - the Authorization Server (AS) typically only needs a few fields to manage login such as Name / Email and a generated user id.

When data becomes domain specific it can become a burden to manage it in the AS, whereas in your product data it is easier to spin up custom UIs etc.

Instead the AS can reach out during token issuing to an API to include important claims in access tokens - such as roles etc. Meanwhile you don't want to expose detailed access tokens to internet clients.

The Curity web site has some good resources on patterns to meet the above requirements - here are a couple of links:

- [IAM Primer](https://curity.io/resources/architect/neo-security/iam-primer/)
- [Claims Best Practices](https://curity.io/resources/architect/claims/claims-best-practices/)

Comment: Thanks, curity has a lot of useful information. Very good resource.